# How to Install Windows Assemblies?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, installation, assembly

I have several websites that use Telerik controls and need to install the assemblies to a new VM running Windows Server 2008 R2. Normally I would drag the *.dll straight into the `C:\Windows\Assembly` folder, but I'm getting faced with an "Access Denied" error.

<s>From what I've read, you can overcome this by logging into the local Administrator account, however I cannot RDP into this account.</s> *(Actually I can, I was wrong)*

What is the easiest way to install these assemblies? Gacutil?

**EDIT**: I should also add, it is best if the solution does not involve disabling the UAC or restarting the server. I would like to avoid service interruption if possible.

Comment: I think this probably needs to move to Stack Overflow. Also, I have read this question a few times now, and I'm sorry, but it sounds to me like you're asking "why am I not able to do something that I do not have permissions/privilege to do?" Sort out the permissions with your administrator.

Comment: @RyanRies I AM the Administrator!

Comment: You're the admin but you can't use your own credentials to do this?

Comment: Oh... I get it. I bet it's a domain-joined machine and *local* admin account is disabled.

Comment: @gparent I am a member of the Administrators group, however I cannot login as the local Administrator account on the VM via RDP! Gosh, read peeps.

Comment: Gosh, you don't need to login via RDP as admin to elevate your privileges peeps! Please don't get angry at me simply because you do not understand my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was indeed able to RDP into the machine as the local Administrator account. For the benefit of those who read this later, both my machine and the server are on a domain controller and my account is in the `Administrators` group, but that was not enough.

To add Assemblies, I simply followed the standard convention of opening two Explorer windows, one at `C:\Windows\assembly` and the other where my DLLs are, then drag the DLLs into my assembly folder. Windows takes care of the rest.

To connect login to the server in such a way as to make this possible, I had to RDP using the following credentials since it's on a domain.

- Computer =`[server_name]`
- User name=`[server_name]\Administrator`

Comment: "As it turns out I was indeed able to RDP into the machine as the local Administrator account."

You're such a troll.

Comment: @RyanRies Wow, that was completely uncalled for. I was told I shouldn't delete my questions, otherwise I would have since I was wrong to begin with. I figured I'd at least post a helpful answer to explain I was wrong. Who's the troll?

Comment: I wasn't trying to actually offend you... I was trying to be funny. Sorry.

Comment: @RyanRies Oh, lol, gotcha, hehe. My bad. :P